# JavaScript change value and data from value in a span

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I need help with this. I need to make the value in the other place change all the time while user session is active. How can I get the value from a span and make other value in a data change?

**Look at there!**

```
 1 <div class="pt-uea-container">
 2  <span class="pt-uea-currency pt-uea-currency-before"> € </span>
 3  <input type="text" class="pt-field pt-uea-custom-amount" autocomplete="off" name="pt_items[1][amount]" id="pt_uea_custom_amount_1" value="199" placeholder="" data-parsley-errors-container="#pt_uea_custom_amount_errors_1">
 4  <input type="hidden" class="pt-field pt-uea-custom-amount-formatted" name="pt_items[1][amount]" value="199" data-pt-price="199">
 5  <input type="hidden" name="pt_items[1][label]" value="Amount:">
 6  <input type="hidden" name="pt_items[1][tax_percentage]" value="0">
 7  <input type="hidden" name="pt_items[1][type]" value="open">
 8  <div id="pt_uea_custom_amount_errors_1"></div>
 9  <span class="form-price-value">85</span>
10 </div>
```

The value in row 9 needs to constantly change values in row 3 and 4 on the same session. Don't mind the value in row 6.

Let me know how I can get this done. Or maybe a different approach?

Greetings!

========

So this is what I got for now from you guys:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var checkViewport = setInterval(function() {
var spanVal = $('.form-price-value').text();
$('#pt_uea_custom_amount_1').val(spanVal);
$('#pt_uea_custom_amount_formatted_1').val(spanVal);
$('#pt_uea_custom_amount_formatted_1').attr('data-pt-price', spanVal);
}, 1000);

});
```

This code works, but it only affects my needs when I put my mouse in pt-field pt-uea-custom-amount and add a space in it. Then it does apply to the page source. But this is not correct. The source needs to get changed too without touching that class or a space or something!

Comment: are you want change value on row 9 with row 3 or 4?

Comment: @Ascaliko YES! Automatic. Value in row 9 does change by itself when products are chosen on the website. So the value in 3 and 4 needs to change with this value in row 9!

Comment: what param to changes the span value?
is it from session or else ?

Comment: No. The value data-pt-price does only change when the input field <input type="text" class="pt-field pt-uea-custom-amount" is clicked or put a space in it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an ideal solution. I'm not sure there is a verified way of listening for when the innerHTML of a span element changes. This sort of stuff is usually based on user interaction, and the value of the span will be modified by your page. The best solution would be to use the same method that updates the span element to update the values of you hidden input fields.
However, I've placed an interval that will run every second, that takes the text value of the span element and gives it to the values of the 2 input fields:

```js
function start() {
  setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById("pt_uea_custom_amount_1").value = document.getElementById("price_value").innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("pt_uea_custom_amount_2").value = document.getElementById("price_value").innerHTML;
  }, 1000);
}
window.onload = start();
```

```html
<div class="pt-uea-container">
  <span class="pt-uea-currency pt-uea-currency-before"> € </span>
  <input type="text" class="pt-field pt-uea-custom-amount" autocomplete="off" name="pt_items[1][amount]" id="pt_uea_custom_amount_1" value="199" placeholder="" data-parsley-errors-container="#pt_uea_custom_amount_errors_1">
  <input type="hidden" class="pt-field pt-uea-custom-amount-formatted" name="pt_items[1][amount]" value="199" data-pt-price="199" id="pt_uea_custom_amount_2">
  <input type="hidden" name="pt_items[1][label]" value="Amount:">
  <input type="hidden" name="pt_items[1][tax_percentage]" value="0">
  <input type="hidden" name="pt_items[1][type]" value="open">
  <div id="pt_uea_custom_amount_errors_1"></div>
  <span id="price_value" class="form-price-value">85</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm very sorry but I don't understand what you did there. Will that code constantly change values when form-price-value is changed?

Comment: No. I was just giving a demonstration to show that you can get a handle of the values and do with them whatever you want. If you can be more specific about what exactly you want to happen, it might be simple enough to do here. What do you want changed when form-price-value changes? Is there a formula to what you want your result to be?

Comment: Sorry maybe I didn't understand. What I want to happen is the following: The value in the span you see on line 9 is actually automatic. This is generated by clicking items on the website. That value in line 9 needs to be in the values in line 3 and 4 by javascript as these row are hidden in front-end.

Answer (score 0):

try this, simple using jquery, you can check in inspect element for value attribute data-pt-price

Update: you can using jquery event `.on()` like change, click, keyup or else to Attach an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements,
you can read the doc [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

here the updated code

```js
$(function() {
    var spanVal = $('#price_value').text();
    $('#pt_uea_custom_amount_1').val(spanVal);
    $('#pt_uea_custom_amount_formatted_1').val(spanVal);
    $('#pt_uea_custom_amount_formatted_1').attr('data-pt-price', spanVal);
    
    $('#pt_uea_custom_amount_1').on('change click keyup', function() {
        $('#pt_uea_custom_amount_formatted_1').val($(this).val());
        $('#price_value').text($(this).val());
        $('#pt_uea_custom_amount_formatted_1').attr('data-pt-price', $(this).val());
    });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pt-uea-container">
  <span class="pt-uea-currency pt-uea-currency-before"> € </span>
  <input type="text" class="pt-field pt-uea-custom-amount" autocomplete="off" name="pt_items[1][amount]" id="pt_uea_custom_amount_1" value="199" placeholder="" data-parsley-errors-container="#pt_uea_custom_amount_errors_1">
  <input type="hidden" class="pt-field pt-uea-custom-amount-formatted" name="pt_items[1][amount]" value="199" data-pt-price="199" id="pt_uea_custom_amount_2">
  <input type="hidden" name="pt_items[1][label]" value="Amount:">
  <input type="hidden" name="pt_items[1][tax_percentage]" value="0">
  <input type="hidden" name="pt_items[1][type]" value="open">
  <div id="pt_uea_custom_amount_errors_1"></div>
  <span id="price_value" class="form-price-value">85</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi! You forgot data-pt-price="value"

Comment: Hi!, you want the  data-pt-price change too ?, look I updated the code

Comment: actually if value  `<span class="form-price-value">85</span>` which is 85 based on session, already dynamically changes, may it can help you

Comment: @Ascakiko! This worked but this does not apply the changes in the values directly in the page itself but only in the view so nothing changes in the source till I put my mouse and enter a space in the inputfield (pt-field pt-uea-custom-amount)

Comment: I got it with :) - var checkViewport = setInterval(function() {

Comment: But still want to see your approach if you want to show me

Comment: ah, you want to reload the value realtime, using `setInterval` its ok. but you can try websocket if you want to implement realtime data

Comment: Hi, @Chocoprins18
so if the value of id pt_uea_custom_amount_1 changes then value of id pt_uea_custom_amount_2 and data-pt-price and span id price_value changes too, Is that what you mean ?
look I update the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with the help of [jQuery](https://jquery.com/).

With the help of jQuery I would do like this.

1. Understanding what input field needs to be tracked for changes. I will give all this field a class (`track-me`).
2. In the document ready, I will look for changes for that tracked field.
3. On change of that field I will get the value and put in other input fields (class `copy-to` - or you can do whatever you like).

See an example below,

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <div class="">
      <input type="text" class="track-me" value=""/>
    </div>
    <div class="">
      <input type="text" class="copy-to" value=""/>
    </div>
    <div class="">
       <input type="text" class="copy-to" value=""/>
    </div>
    <div class="">
      <input type="text" class="copy-to" value=""/>
    </div> 
    <div class="">
      <div class="">Please type anything in the first input box</div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.track-me').change(function (){
        $('.copy-to').val($(this).val())
    });
});
```

I made comments in the above jQuery code so you can understand. Also, I have made a fiddle so you can play and have a look. In this fiddle, I am using `Bootstrap4` just for the purpose of styling, you don't have to worry about that.

**Link to fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/anjanasilva/r21u4fmh/21/

I hope this helps. Feel free to ask me any questions if you have. Cheers.

Comment: I don't think this is what he meant

Comment: Hi @Anjana. I think you didn't understand. What I want to happen is the following: The value in the span you see on line 9 is actually automatic. This is generated by clicking items on the website. That value in line 9 needs to be in the values in line 3 and 4 by javascript or jQuery :) as these rows are hidden in front-end

Comment: So at the end, everything needs to have the same value as in the span in row 9!

Comment: @Chocoprins18 : Sorry about that. I have updated my answer. Is that any good?

Comment: @Ascaliko Thank you for the headsup.

Answer (score 0):

[MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) should work here..

```
const formValuePrice = document.querySelector( '.form-price-value' );
const inputText = document.querySelector( 'input[type="text"]' );

// timer to change values
window.setInterval( () => {
    formValuePrice.textContent = Math.round( Math.random() * 100 );
}, 1000 );

// mutation observer
const observer = new MutationObserver( ( mutationsList ) => {
    inputText.value = formValuePrice.textContent;
} );

observer.observe( formValuePrice, { childList: true } );
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LgWXrz?editors=1111

Comment: How can I apply this to my HTML shown above? I don't understand this :(

Comment: the key part is watching for changes to formValuePrice with the MutationObserver and then reacting accordingly. the codepen link above shows it in action